# MySQL CASE statement with subquery for histogram

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to gather data to create a histogram. I want to create histogram of number of times users login to the system. My goal is to utilize the function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860992) answer, but if there is a better way, that's fine with me too.

My login table is similar to this:

```
datetime | userid
```

My first step is to get a count of the number of times a user has logged in:

```
select count(userid) from logins group by userid
```

This returns a nice result set that is similar to:

```
1325
761
4012
1204
662
1841
15
1698
...
```

My question is, how can I adapt this to utilize the `SELECT CASE WHEN` method from the linked answer. That code looks like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 13 AND 17 THEN '13-17' 
            WHEN age BETWEEN 18 AND 25 THEN '18-25' 
            ELSE '26+' END AS AgeGroup,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY AgeGroup
```

In my case, though, `age` in the `WHEN` clauses, is a subquery that I don't think needs to be run for each `WHEN`. What is an efficient way to utilize the counts I have to use in these bins?

Comment: How do you want group the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like you are looking to make ranges of number of logins, in which case you first count the login attempts per user and then combine the individual counts into different buckets.

The following query will give you *number of users* who logged in *1-2* times, *3-4 times*, and *4+* times.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN total_logins BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN '1-2' 
            WHEN total_logins BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN '3-4' 
            ELSE '4+' 
       END AS LoginGroup,
       COUNT(userid) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS total_logins 
  FROM login 
  GROUP BY userid
) t
GROUP BY LoginGroup
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a66396/2

---

If you need to make buckets based on actual login count then use `SUM(total_logins)` instead of `COUNT(user_id)` like the query below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN total_logins BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN '1-2' 
            WHEN total_logins BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN '3-4' 
            ELSE '4+' 
       END AS LoginGroup,
       SUM(total_logins) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS total_logins 
  FROM login 
  GROUP BY userid
) t
GROUP BY LoginGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the case to the group by:

```
select case when age between 13
                and 17 then '13-17' when age between 18
                and 25 then '18-25' else '26+' end as AgeGroup,
    COUNT(*) as total
from MyTable
group by case when age between 13
                and 17 then '13-17' when age between 18
                and 25 then '18-25' else '26+' end
```

If you want to write the case once, do:

```
select AgeGroup,
    count(*) as total
from (
    select case when age between 13
                    and 17 then '13-17' when age between 18
                    and 25 then '18-25' else '26+' end as AgeGroup
    from MyTable
    ) t
group by AgeGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look this code.

```
SELECT 
CASE age 
    WHEN BETWEEN 13 AND 17 THEN '13-17' 
    WHEN BETWEEN 18 AND 25 THEN '18-25' 
    ELSE '26+'
END AS AgeGroup,
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CASE age 
    WHEN BETWEEN 13 AND 17 THEN '13-17' 
    WHEN BETWEEN 18 AND 25 THEN '18-25' 
    ELSE '26+'
END
```